SwiftUI paging with custom scrolling control
I'm new to SwiftUI, and I'm trying to design a paging view associated with a custom tab bar control. The tab bar should be scrollable and synced with the main view. Tap to select on the tab bar should also work, and scrolling through the main pages should sync with the tab bar
So far I managed to get most of my desired behavior. The only thing missing is that scrolling (draggesture) the tab bar items does not update in real time, only onEnded action. Not sure what I'm doing wrong with the gesture controls.
//
//  Home.swift
//  ScrollPicker
//
//  Created by Felipe Quintella Correia on 7/19/24.
//

import SwiftUI

struct TabView2: View {
    @State private var tabs: [TabModel] = [
        .init(id: TabModel.Tab.research),
        .init(id: TabModel.Tab.deployment),
        .init(id: TabModel.Tab.analytics),
        .init(id: TabModel.Tab.audience),
        .init(id: TabModel.Tab.privacy)
    ]
    @State private var activeTab: TabModel.Tab = .research
    @State private var tabBarScrollState: TabModel.Tab?
    @State private var mainViewScrollState: TabModel.Tab?
    @State private var progress: CGFloat = .zero
    @State private var tabBarProgress: CGFloat = .zero
    private var tabBarDragging: Bool {
        gestureScroll != .zero
    }
    
    @State private var scroll: CGFloat = .zero
    @GestureState private var gestureScroll: CGFloat = .zero
    
    private var scrollingGesture: some Gesture {
        DragGesture()
            .updating(self.$gestureScroll) { value, gestureScroll, _ in
                gestureScroll = -value.translation.width
            }
            .onEnded { value in
                scroll -= value.translation.width
                let origin = -(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width/2 - tabs[0].size.width/2)
                var inputRange: [CGFloat] = []
                
                for i in 0..<tabs.count {
                    var sum = origin
                    if i > 0 {
                        sum += tabs[0].size.width/2 + 20
                        for j in 1..<i {
                            sum += tabs[j].size.width + 20
                        }
                        sum += tabs[i].size.width/2
                    }
                    inputRange.append(sum)
                }
                let outputRange: [CGFloat] = tabs.indices.compactMap { return CGFloat($0) }
                withAnimation(.snappy) {
                    tabBarProgress = (scroll + gestureScroll).interpolate(inputRange: inputRange, outputRange: outputRange)
                    activeTab = tabs[Int(tabBarProgress.rounded(.toNearestOrAwayFromZero))].id
                    tabBarScrollState = tabs[Int(tabBarProgress.rounded(.toNearestOrAwayFromZero))].id
                    mainViewScrollState = tabs[Int(tabBarProgress.rounded(.toNearestOrAwayFromZero))].id
                }
            }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Text("Main progress \(progress)")
            Text("Tab Bar progress \(tabBarProgress)")
            Text("Active Tab \(activeTab)")
            HeaderView()
            CustomTabBar()
            
            GeometryReader {
                let size = $0.size
                
                ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                    LazyHStack(spacing: 0) {
                        ForEach(tabs) { tab in
                            Text(tab.id.rawValue)
                                .frame(width: size.width, height: size.height)
                                .contentShape(.rect)
                        }
                    }
                    .scrollTargetLayout()
                    .rect { rect in
                        if !tabBarDragging {
                            progress = -rect.minX / size.width
                        }
                    }
                }
                .scrollPosition(id: $mainViewScrollState)
                .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
                .scrollTargetBehavior(.paging)
                .onChange(of: mainViewScrollState) { oldValue, newValue in
                    if let newValue {
                        withAnimation(.snappy) {
                            tabBarScrollState = newValue
                            activeTab = newValue
                        }
                    }
                }
                .onAppear {
//                    activeTab = .analytics
//                    tabBarScrollState = .analytics
//                    mainViewScrollState = . analytics
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func HeaderView() -> some View {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: "shazam.logo")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(height: 50)
            
            Spacer(minLength: 0)
            
            Button("", systemImage: "plus.circle") {
                
            }
            .font(.title2)
            .tint(.primary)
            
            Button("", systemImage: "bell") {
                
            }
            .font(.title2)
            .tint(.primary)
            
            Button(action: {}, label: {
                Image("NewYork")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                    .clipShape(.circle)
                    .border(.red)
            })
            
        }
        .padding(15)
        .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(.gray.opacity(0.3))
                .frame(height:1)
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func CustomTabBar() -> some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            let inputRange = tabs.indices.compactMap { return CGFloat($0) }
            let outputRange = tabs.compactMap { return $0.size.width }
            let outputWidthRange: [CGFloat] = [0.0,
                                               tabs[0].size.width/2 + 20 + tabs[1].size.width/2,
                                               tabs[0].size.width/2 + 20 + tabs[1].size.width + 20 + tabs[2].size.width/2,
                                               tabs[0].size.width/2 + 20 + tabs[1].size.width + 20 + tabs[2].size.width + 20 + tabs[3].size.width/2,
                                               tabs[0].size.width/2 + 20 + tabs[1].size.width + 20 + tabs[2].size.width + 20 + tabs[3].size.width + 20 + tabs[4].size.width/2
            ]
            let indicatorWidth = progress.interpolate(inputRange: inputRange, outputRange: outputRange)
            let indicatorPosition = progress.interpolate(inputRange: inputRange, outputRange: outputWidthRange)
            
            HStack(spacing: 20) {
                ForEach($tabs) { $tab in
//                    Button(action: {
//                        withAnimation(.snappy) {
//                            activeTab = tab.id
//                            tabBarScrollState = tab.id
//                            mainViewScrollState = tab.id
//                        }
//                    }) {
//                        Text(tab.id.rawValue)
//                            .padding(.vertical, 12)
//                            .foregroundStyle(activeTab == tab.id ? Color.primary : .gray )
//                            .contentShape(.rect)
//                    }
//                    .buttonStyle(.plain)
                    Text(tab.id.rawValue)
                        .padding(.vertical, 12)
                        .foregroundStyle(activeTab == tab.id ? Color.primary : .gray )
                        .contentShape(.rect)
                    .rect { rect in
                        tab.size = rect.size
                        tab.minX = rect.minX
                    }
                    .onTapGesture {
                        withAnimation(.snappy) {
                            activeTab = tab.id
                            tabBarScrollState = tab.id
                            mainViewScrollState = tab.id
                        }
                    }
                    .gesture(scrollingGesture)
                    .border(.red)
                }
            }
            .rect { rect in
                if !tabBarDragging {
                    scroll = -rect.minX
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: scroll) {
                if !tabBarDragging {
                    let origin = -(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width/2 - tabs[0].size.width/2)
                    var inputRange: [CGFloat] = []
                    
                    for i in 0..<tabs.count {
                        var sum = origin
                        if i > 0 {
                            sum += tabs[0].size.width/2 + 20
                            for j in 1..<i {
                                sum += tabs[j].size.width + 20
                            }
                            sum += tabs[i].size.width/2
                        }
                        inputRange.append(sum)
                    }
                    let outputRange: [CGFloat] = tabs.indices.compactMap { return CGFloat($0) }
                    tabBarProgress = (scroll + gestureScroll).interpolate(inputRange: inputRange, outputRange: outputRange)
                }
//                progress = tabBarProgress
            }
            .gesture(scrollingGesture)
            .scrollTargetLayout()
            .offset(x: -indicatorPosition)
            .padding(.leading, UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width/2 - tabs[0].size.width/2)
            .padding(.trailing, UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width/2 - tabs[tabs.count-1].size.width/2)
            .border(.green)
        }
        .scrollDisabled(true)
        .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
            ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(.gray.opacity(0.3))
                    .frame(height: 1)
                
                let inputRange = tabs.indices.compactMap { return CGFloat($0) }
                let outputRange = tabs.compactMap { return $0.size.width }
                let outputPositionRange = tabs.compactMap { return $0.minX }
                let indicatorWidth = progress.interpolate(inputRange: inputRange, outputRange: outputRange)
                let indicatorPosition = progress.interpolate(inputRange: inputRange, outputRange: outputPositionRange)
                
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(.primary)
                    .frame(width: indicatorWidth, height: 1.5)
                    .offset(x: indicatorPosition)
            }
        }
        //        .safeAreaPadding(.leading, UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width/2 - tabs[0].size.width/2)
        //        .safeAreaPadding(.horizontal, 15)
        .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
    }
}

#Preview {
    TabView2()
}


I don't get why my DragGesture().updating(){} function doesn't work, I've even tried displaying the gestureScroll variable on screen and it doesn't update at all
@State private var scroll: CGFloat = .zero
    @GestureState private var gestureScroll: CGFloat = .zero
    
    private var scrollingGesture: some Gesture {
        DragGesture()
            .updating(self.$gestureScroll) { value, gestureScroll, _ in
                gestureScroll = -value.translation.width
            }
            .onEnded { value in
                scroll -= value.translation.width
                let origin = -(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width/2 - tabs[0].size.width/2)
                var inputRange: [CGFloat] = []
                
                for i in 0..<tabs.count {
                    var sum = origin
                    if i > 0 {
                        sum += tabs[0].size.width/2 + 20
                        for j in 1..<i {
                            sum += tabs[j].size.width + 20
                        }
                        sum += tabs[i].size.width/2
                    }
                    inputRange.append(sum)
                }
                let outputRange: [CGFloat] = tabs.indices.compactMap { return CGFloat($0) }
                withAnimation(.snappy) {
                    tabBarProgress = (scroll + gestureScroll).interpolate(inputRange: inputRange, outputRange: outputRange)
                    activeTab = tabs[Int(tabBarProgress.rounded(.toNearestOrAwayFromZero))].id
                    tabBarScrollState = tabs[Int(tabBarProgress.rounded(.toNearestOrAwayFromZero))].id
                    mainViewScrollState = tabs[Int(tabBarProgress.rounded(.toNearestOrAwayFromZero))].id
                }
            }
    }

This is the behavior I'm getting:
Video
Basically, I'm trying to replicate the behavior on the tabbar of Copilot Money app if anyone has seen it:
Video
